# Stopping a subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, subprocess, libraries

I have several python scripts that run at the same time with the use of the subprocess library. However, i want to be able to stop all processes when an event happens, such as the press of a button. I have tried several things, but none of them seem to work.
I'm using Windows with Python 3.8.0

Below is my code that opens all of the processes.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("python Program1.py")
subprocess.Popen("python Program2.py")
subprocess.Popen("python Program3.py")
subprocess.Popen("python Program4.py")
subprocess.Popen("python Program5.py")
subprocess.Popen("python Program6.py")
subprocess.Popen("python Program7.py")
```

I cant figure out how to end the processes with the subprocess library or any other ones.
I have also tried the following
`proc1.kill()`

`p.terminate()`

```
def pkill (process_name):
    try:
        killed = os.system('tskill ' + process_name)
    except Exception as e:
        killed = 0
    return killed
pkill("PROGRAM")
```

And with the one above, i have tried putting `except Exception, e:` And also putting `pkill("PROGRAM.py")` but that doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: You have to save the process into a variable to kill or term it later.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry i dont quite understand, How should i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the launched Process Ids:

```
import os
import subprocess

processes = []
for x in range(0,9):
    p = subprocess.Popen("python Program.py %s" % x)
    processes.append(p.pid)  # keep the processIds!

for p in processes:
    os.system('taskkill /F /PID ' + p)
```